# Find $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{(z-\frac{1}{2}-i)(z-1-\frac{3i}{2})(z-1-\frac{i}{2})(z-\frac{3}{2}-i)}\, $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, curves

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{[(z-\frac{1}{2}-i)(z-1-\frac{3i}{2})(z-1-\frac{i}{2})(z-\frac{3}{2}-i)]}$ and let $\gamma$ be the polygon $[0,2,2+2i,2i,0]$. Find $\int_{\gamma}^{} f$ .

I'm trying to use the partial fractions decomposition method, but it's getting too long and I'm lost in the accounts. I do not know if the author expects me to do so. Can anybody help me?
Conway, pg. 96, prob., 7.

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: Partial fractions decomposition is not needed.

Comment: Conway not found. Which one?

Comment: Functions of One Complex Variable, Second Edition.

Comment: Can you relate the integral to $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} f(z)\,dz\,?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the residue theorem: $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=2\pi i\sum_i\textrm{res}_{z_i}$. So the problem essentially is to evaluate the residue of each pole. The poles are at:
$1/2+i$, $1+3i/2$, $1+i/2$, $3/2+i$.
Simply check which are in your boundary and evaluate the residues.

Answer (score 2):

Your $\gamma $ encloses the poles of $f.$ Suppose we now consider the circle $|z|=R$ for any $R>\sqrt 8.$ Such a circle encloses $\gamma,$ hence $f$ is analytic on and between these two contours. Thus by Cauchy's theorem,

$$\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz =\int_{|z|=R} f(z)\, dz.$$

Now think of estimating the last integral as $R\to \infty.$ We will have $|f(z)|$ on the order of $1/R^4,$ while the arc length of the contour is $2\pi R.$ It follows that the last integral $\to 0$ as $R\to \infty.$ Since it is constant for large $R,$ it must equal $0$ for such $R.$ Hence $\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz = 0.$

Comment: Since my hint didn't impress you, I turned it into a solution. It really is a much easier route to the answer.